# Java serialization library without need of no-arg constructors and implementation of Serializable

Tags: java, serialization, constructor, serializable

Is there is any way in java-world to serialize without need of no-arg constructors and implementation of Serializable?

Comment: Java serialization does not require a no argument constructor.

Comment: Yes it does. See the Object Serialization Specification and Tom Hawtin's comment.

Comment: EJP, that is not correct, and Steve Kuo is. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539 . Your serializable class *must* "Have access to the no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable superclass". In other words, if you look up the inheritance tree towards Object, the first non-serializable class you see must have a non-private noarg constructor. More to come...

Comment: Your own serializable class does *not* require a noarg constructor. See the description of the behaviour of readObject() at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html . "Reading an object is *analogous* to running the constructors of a new object. Memory is allocated for the object and initialized to zero (NULL)...". readObject is about to deserialize data into the fields of the object, so it would be wasteful to execute any constructor that would set an incorrect value into those fields. Just zeroing out the memory makes sense.

Comment: @ConcreteGannet As I didn't say a *Serializable class* requires a no-arg constructor, and as I *did* say that *Serialization* requires a no-arg constructor, which your quote also states, I am indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org), [JSX](http://jsx.org/) or [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html).

Answer (score 2):

[JBoss Serialization](http://www.jboss.org/serialization) is a drop-in replacement for standard java serialization, which does not require you to implement `java.io.Serializable`. Other than that (and the fact that it's much faster), it's the same as the standard serialization mechanism (it even uses the same `ObjectInput` and `ObjectOutput` interfaces.

P.S. It has no dependency on other JBoss stuff, it's just one of the JBoss low-level libraries broken out as a separate project.

Answer (score 1):

A horrific way to do it would be to build a parallel hierarchy of classes, each one standing in for one of the classes in the third-party hierarchy, each of which implements Externalizable, and writes itself by writing the appropriate fields from the third-party object.

I wouldn't, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in some cases you can force serialization despite the Type's declarations.  However there is inherent risk as the class may have fields that are not serializable, which will cause runtime exceptions.

I'm curious though as you get no-arg default constructors for free, unless you have written custom constructors.  Also implmenting Serializable takes 30 seconds of find/replace.

Is there a reason you are trying to avoid these?

Comment: Yes, there are many objects of 3-rd party classes(to source of which I have no access) in tree I want to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

> **...and implementation of Serializable?**

Unfortunately not. All Serializable objects **must** implement `java.io.Serializable`. As for your first part of the question, you can use `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` to serialize objects to byte array and vice versa.

The following example shows how to:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(Object object) throws IOException {
        if (!isSerializable(object)) {
            throw new IOException("Object '" + object.getClass().getName() + "' is not serializable.");
        }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                logger.error("Closing of ObjectOutputStream failed.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static Object toObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Object object = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null; 

    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        object = ois.readObject();
    } finally {
        if (ois != null) {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                logger.error("Closing of ObjectInputStream failed.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

Comment: Elite, this code demonstrates how to serialize and deserialize, but the crux of the question is how to make your class serializable, so that when an instance of your class is passed to the toByteArray method you wrote above, there will not be a NotSerializableException.

Comment: @Concrete Gannet, as I said on my post (please read), it's only by extending `Serializable` that your class is able to enter serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Eishay Smith has done [a benchmarking of Java serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/) which includes some [information about each one](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/ToolBehavior), although it doesn't say whether they use no-arg constructors (and in many cases, they don't even work with arbitrary objects, so the question is moot). That might be worth a look.

Comment: I can't see anything about constructors there.

Comment: You're right, there's nothing about that on that page - edited accordingly. Somewhere associated with that project, there's a more detailed description of each tool, which includes things like that. I can't find it, though.

Answer (score 0):

And [Databoard](http://dev.simantics.org/index.php/Org.simantics.databoard), it can serialize bean-style, record-style and immutable-style classes. You can also write own class-external binding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a range of alternatives as other people have said. If you want to stick with standard Java serialization with writeObject and readObject, you could write your own adapter class that inherits from a third party class, implement Serializable on your own class, and override writeObject and readObject, in other words, implement custom serialization for your class.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=251942 explanation.

The only requirement on the constructor for a class that implements `Serializable` is that the first non-serializable superclass in its inheritence hierarchy must have a no-argument constructor.

1. Serializeble without no-argument constructor as extends `Object` with with no-argument constructor

   ```
    public class MySerializableClass implements Serializable {
       public MySerializableClass (...)...
    }
   ```
2. Serializeble without no-argument constructor as extends `MyFirstClass` with with no-argument constructor

   ```
    public class MyFirstClass {
    }
    public class MySecondClass extends MyFirstClass implements Serializable {
       public MySecondClass (...)...
    }
   ```
3. NOT serializeble as `MyFirstClass` is not implement `Serializable` AND have not default constructor.

   ```
    public class MyFirstClass {
       public MyFirstClass (...)...
    }
    public class MySecondClass extends MyFirstClass implements Serializable {
       public MySecondClass (...)...
    }
   ```