# Why can't I serialize an object without a no-arg constructor even though it implements Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, uuid, titan, kryo

I am trying to serialize a UUID with the Titan graph database and I believe I cannot because per the definition of Serializable, java.util.UUID fails to provide a no-arg constructor.

(See top of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html for this)

Given that java.util.UUID claims to implement Serializable, what's going on here? Is this just a historical mistake that can't be removed for backward compatbility, or is there a specific technical reason for this weird (and to me, annoying) choice?

Update: Per the answer, UUID actually *is* Serializable and I misread the no-arg constructor rule which is subtle and does not actually require a no-arg constructor in the same class. The reason I couldn't serialize mine is that *Titan*  (or its dependencies) adds a stricter no-arg *declared* constructor rule -- not core Java. I was confused as to who was imposing this rule, Java or Titan.

Comment: Do you get a stack trace?  Could you add it?

Comment: Have a look here, this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124907/java-serialization-library-without-need-of-no-arg-constructors-and-implementatio

Comment: `UUID` is serializable, and you're misreading the documentation: the no-arg constructor rule only applies when a serializable class extends a non-serializable class and manages the serialiation of that class' fields. Rather than make assumptions, show your code and stack trace. -1 until you do.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/oVWNFI

Comment: @kdgregory That's not correct either. The nearest non-serializable base class must provide the no-args constructor; it has nothing to do with 'and manages the serialization of that class'; and all Serializable classes ultimately extend a non-serializable class, because of java.lang.Object.

Comment: @EJP - To quote the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html): To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state.

Comment: Now, perhaps in Oz the word "manage" means something different from "assume responsibility"; I was paraphrasing and I should have quoted earlier. But regardless, the OP is not running into a problem because `UUID` doesn't provide a no-args constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot all, you guys are right, I should give more specific code. I won't need to though because my question is answered now -- I'll explain under EJP's answer that I will mark as correct.

Comment: @kdgregory It's strange wording, but the fact is that *any* Serializable class's nearest non-serializable base class must have an accessible no-args constructor, *regardless* of whether or not the serializable class 'assumes responsibility' etc. It says so somewhere in the Specification, which is the normative reference. Agree with your last sentence completely.

Comment: @EJP - agreed regarding the need to have a 0-arg ctor somewhere. I believe that the documentation is directed more toward people who want to implement writeObject and readObject. I would normally consider that to be done by the immediate subclass of the non-serializable class.

Comment: @kdgregory I've submitted a bug report about that wording. The Object Serialization Specification simply says "A Serializable class must do the following: ... Have access to the no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable superclass".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Serializable class doesn't need a no-args constructor. Its nearest non-serializable base class does.

You've misread the specification.

Comment: So, the way this came up is I was trying to use the Titan graph database which uses the Kryo serializer. One of my types was of UUID and could not be serialized due to having no no-arg constructor. However, EJP, I have reread the spec and see you are right, that is not the exact requirement. Therefore this is actually a bug in Titan/Kryo, which contains in KryoSerializer#isValidClass the following: "for (Constructor c : type.getDeclaredConstructors()) if (c.getParameterTypes().length==0) return true;"

Comment: But where does it say that the rules for Object Serialization apply exactly to Kryo, and that there are no other rules? That's the only way it can be a bug in Kryo.

Comment: Where does it say that they don't? When you use a common basic term like Serializable that has an accepted definition in context, the onus is on you to explicitly say you're using the term differently. I trust Kryo probably mentions this though, not the point since the affected code is in Titan's use of Kryo, not Kryo. And I was about to submit a bug for Titan but noticed Titan does actually mention this gotcha, making it not a bug but a documented difference. So I guess I won't be filing anything anywhere. I just was confused by Titan's documentation. Thanks to your explanation, I'm now not.

Comment: @DomingoIgnacio If you want the rules for Kryo serialization you should be looking at the Kryo documentation. If you want the rules for Java Object Serialization you should be looking at the Java Object Serialization Specification. Importing rules from one to the other doesn't make sense.